# How to implement loss function for CNN-SVM implementation

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, matlab

I am using Matlab R2018b and am trying to infuse svm classifier within CNN. My plan is to use CNN only as a feature extractor and use SVM as the classifier. I know people have already implemented it a few years back either in tensorflow or in other platforms. In implementing this I got stuck at a point during backward propagation. I got puzzled about which loss function I need to implement to upgrade the gradients and the parameters.

Few points came up during this:

1. I got a feeling to implement the hinge loss here. But which form of hinge loss should I implement? Should I move on to the second form of hinge loss implementation for calculating loss during backward propagation?
2. Besides, calculating the backward loss, should I calculate the forward loss as well to find out the loss occurred in the model?

Any form of advice doing this CNN-svm infusion will be appreciated as I am unable to find any such material implemented in Matlab to get help.

Thanks.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question. You could train your CNN normally, with logistic regression. Use that to extract features and train SVM.

Comment: @ Illuminati0x5B: thanks for your suggestion. actually, I have already extracted the features from the FC layer. After doing this, I fed those to the SVM classifier. All two of these steps have done during forwarding propagation. I stuck in a phase of backward propagation where I need to calculate the backward loss. I try to find out what kind of loss function, I'll implement here. I assume it must be some vector loss calculation. right?